# Rails how to submit a form with ajax and include some jquery variables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to submit a form via ajax and include some variables that i'm setting via jquery.

/views/applications/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@application, :html => {:class => "organizer"}, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  // fields in here
<% end %>
```

/controllers/applications_controller.rb

```
  # PUT /applications/1
  # PUT /applications/1.json
  def update
    @application = Application.find(params[:id])
    p params[:xposition]     # these get set in jquery
    p params[:application]   # these get set in jquery
    respond_to do |format|
      if @application.update_attributes(params[:application])
        @curr_app = ApplicationField.last

        format.html { redirect_to @application, notice: 'Application was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js { render action: "update" }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @application.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js { render action: "update" }
      end
    end
  end
```

/assets/javascripts/applications.js

```
$('.organizer').submit(function() {

        var dataToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
        var field_values = [];
        var x_values = [];
        var y_values = [];

        // i add values to the arrays above here

        for(i = 0; i < field_values.length; ++i) {
            dataToSubmit += "&field_name="+field_values[i]+"&xposition="+x_values[i]+"&yposition="+y_values[i];
        }

        $.post($(this).attr('action'), dataToSubmit);   
    });
```

With my current code, when the form is submitted, it goes directly to the controller, and then the $.post call in my jquery code calls the same controller and passes xpostion and yposition in the data of the $.post call (which is what i want).

How can i make it so only my form doesn't get submitted twice - once by hitting the controller as soon as the submit button is clicked and once from my $.post call?

I thought :remote => true makes it so the form wouldn't call the controller directly?

**EDIT**

If :remote => true sends an ajax request without me having to use jquery's $.post method to send the ajax request manually, how can i send extra variables along with the ajax request that automatically gets made by using :remote => true?

**EDIT**

Here's a snippet from my server log

```
Started PUT "/applications/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-18 00:06:19 -0600
Processing by ApplicationsController#update as */*
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3LOzuiL/PU6HypJ4OeN5H9yrX3Xyk0VT6XpcFYd1wY0=", "application"=>{"application_field_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"8"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"9"}}}, "field_name"=>"aaa", "xposition"=>"0", "yposition"=>"0", "id"=>"3"}
  Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`subdomain` = 'localhost' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Application Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `applications`.* FROM `applications` WHERE `applications`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1


Started PUT "/applications/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-18 00:06:19 -0600
Processing by ApplicationsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3LOzuiL/PU6HypJ4OeN5H9yrX3Xyk0VT6XpcFYd1wY0=", "application"=>{"application_field_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"8"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"9"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"3"}
  Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`subdomain` = 'localhost' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Application Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `applications`.* FROM `applications` WHERE `applications`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: If i remove my jquery block from applications.js completely, then i only see one request sent in my server log and it's this one `Processing by ApplicationsController#update as JS
`. If it's automatically sending this via ajax, how can i add pass extra jquery variables with the ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to stop all handlers except yours. Try this:

```
$('.organizer').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stops default behavior
  e.stopPropagation(); // prevents event bubbling
  // you code
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This seems to work. It results in only 1 request going to the controller and it's my explicit ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the for from being submitted normally by preventing its default behaviour. To do this add an event parameter to you function and call `.preventDefault()`

```
$('.organizer').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
        var field_values = [];
        var x_values = [];
        var y_values = [];

        // i add values to the arrays above here

        for(i = 0; i < field_values.length; ++i) {
            dataToSubmit += "&field_name="+field_values[i]+"&xposition="+x_values[i]+"&yposition="+y_values[i];
        }

        $.post($(this).attr('action'), dataToSubmit);   
    });
```

Comment: Apparently the problem is not that because if i remove the entire `$('.organizer').submit..` block, the form still gets submitted.

Comment: @Catfish that is why you are using a submit handler, to send the data via ajax. You need the submit handler to prevent the form from submitting (using `.preventDefault()`)

Comment: I tried your solution and it doesn't work. The form gets submitted twice. If i remove everything from my applications.js file, the form still gets submitted whether i have a `$('.organizer').submit` in there or not.